# My Ender 3 v2 has randomly turned off and no longer turns on. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Tags: creality-ender-3

About a day ago my Ender 3 v2 just shut off while printing. It didn’t really bother me since this has happened many times before and switching the power supply off and then turning it on would fix the issue. This time though the printer is no longer turning on. I opened up the power supply and the indicator light is turning on, but when I check the outputs with a voltage meter it says 0. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Could be a fuse or some other part blown... are you certified to perform mains voltage work?

Comment: Is it under warranty still?  There's no reason to fiddle with something that should be replaced under warranty.

Comment: And there is even less reason to fiddle with mains voltage inside a running power supply unit - which might kill you if you mishandle it.

Comment: Check all the connections - I had something similar and fixed it by pushing a plug back into its socket.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. There was no fuses that were blown and all the wires were secured in their sockets. My printer was already out of warranty so I ended up just ordering a new one which will arrive today.

Comment: I don't know what the PSU of an Ender 3 v2 looks like, but lots of PSU have a last-resort fuse: a fuse that's internal, only works once and is not easily replaced. It's quite possibly that one blew out and that's why the indicator still works while the rest doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular power supply, but usually they have a fuse. In your case it's more likely to be a capacitator causing the problem though as fuses are not intermittent problems and they're usually situated before any board lights for obvious reasons. They normally either work or fail.

I'm assuming you checked for loose wires and connections.

This is a job for an electrician, capacitators cannot easily be tested without proper equipment and need some good soldering skills to replace properly. If they're liquid filled then you can sometimes see doming on the top of the capacitator where it looks a bit deformed. Or even a leak. If they're solid state then there is no easy way to see if they're failing.